# Problem writing to csv file, string is over multiple columns

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write some data to a csv file. however one of the words is being written over multiple columns when it's meant to be in just one. And the rest of the data isn't showing up.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
header = ['Type','cap pos', 'cap neg', 'growth pos', 'growth neg']
data = ["My code", counter_cp, counter_cn, counter_gp, counter_gn]
            
with open('Comparison1.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerow(header)
     writer.writerows(data)
```

counter_cp etc are int types, from a for loop I did before which counted the number of a certain thing. When I do `print(counter_cp, type(counter_cp)` I get: `Counter :  430 type : <class 'int'>`.

The output is coming out like:

| Type | cap pos | cap neg | growth pos | growth neg |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | y |  | c | o | d | e |

I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong? It's meant to come out like:

| Type | cap pos | cap neg | growth pos | growth neg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| My code | 430 | 260 | 452 | 297 |

Comment: Looks like `data` is really only a single row - is that not meant to be a list of lists? If not - then use `.writerow` instead of `.writerows`...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you used `writer.writerows()` instead of `writer.writerow()`.